# Debian runlevel scripts not running on shutdown, reboot, etc. Priorities?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, debian, runlevel

I have a problem, where my shutdown runlevel MySQL bash scripts are not executed. rcS.d, however works always.

I used scripts in init.d folder to be run on different runlevels. Currently, the only one I have gotten to work, is the bash script that inserts a row about the server booting up.

The problem is, that when I use the same method to run a script while the runlevels are 0 or 6, for example, the script is never run. I think it might be a priority issue. Look at the picture below (The priority is the same as the kill priorities for apache, etc...). Are the scripts run in alphabetical order or could I bump all priorities up by one somehow?

I'm guessing the problem is that the services are killed before the script is run - apache killed @ 1 & mysql killed @ 2. The same script works for booting up - a bash mysql insert command in the file.

[image]

Comment: Scripts with `K` prefix are called with the `stop` parameter when entering a runlevel. Scripts with `S` prefix are called with the `start` parameter. This is done in alphabetical order (i.e. `K` before `S` and lower numbers first). If concurrency is configured (`/etc/init.d/rc`), scripts may be run in parallel depending on dependencies in their LSB header comments, otherwise they will be run sequentially. It is usually not a good idea to manually edit any existing links (because they are managed by maintainer scripts via package management and your changes will be overwritten on upgrade).

Comment: To your question: Are you sure your script is not executed? It's more likely there is some error due to killed services as you mentioned. You should post some code, otherwise it's just guessing.